# Racket - Applying a Boolean to a list of lists

Tags: recursion, boolean, racket

I have a function that utilizes a Boolean to replace the first number in a list with 1, regardless of its value:

f({(0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0), ...}) = {(1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0), ...}

So far I have

```
(define (procB set)
  (map (λ (lst1) ((number? (first lst1)) (cons 1 (rest lst1)))) set))
```

The trouble is when the function is applied to the remaining parts of the set.  I get the standard error

```
application: not a procedure;
expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
 given: #t
```

I get that it isn't working because there is a Boolean (given: #t), but I am not quite sure how to fix it.

Comment: The error reported states that you tried to apply a value as if it were a function - in this case, the interpreter assumes that the result of `(number? (first lst1))` is a function, which is not. If you intended to perform an action depending on the result of a boolean comparison, then use `if` or `cond`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an `if` expression to test if the first value is a number - and if it is not, what should we do? we could leave it alone. Also you seem to have a couple of misplaced parentheses, this should fix the bugs:

```
(define (procB set)
  (map (λ (lst1)
         (if (number? (first lst1))
             (cons 1 (rest lst1))
             lst1))
       set))
```

Now it works as expected:

```
(procB '((0 1 0) (0 0 1) (1 0 0)))
=> '((1 1 0) (1 0 1) (1 0 0))
```

Just to be sure... if the sublists can only contain numbers, then the `if` expression is superfluous, all you have to do inside the `lambda` is `(cons 1 (rest lst1))`.

Comment: Thank you.  This works very well.  I shortened the code to not include the Boolean, but if I do need one, I will now know how to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're missing an `if`. In your `lambda` in the `map`, `(number? (first lst1))` will resolve to `#t`. It will then try to apply the procedure `#t` to `(cons 1 (rest lst1))` which gives you the error you're seeing. I suspect you want your `lambda` to be closer to

```
(lambda (lst1)
    (if (number? (first lst1))
        ; then cons 1 with the rest
        ; else don't replace with a 1
```

Comment: Thanks.  I figured out an easier way to do it, but if I ever need to map a Boolean, I will know exactly to do.